# Rails Scopes - I Don't Want Any Scope Added in Some Conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm somewhat new to Rails and have been working with the scopes in Rails 3.2 . I like how the scope separates out the code from the controller.  But, when I'm building a query with scopes, I can't figure out how to *not* add a scope in certain situations.  See the example below...

In my CarsController class

```
    if !params[:make_name].blank?  
        @cars = Car.by_make(params[:make_name]).find(:all, :group => "name")
    else      
        @cars = Car.all
```

In my Car model class.  The code is trying to say "If the make_name string is 'all', then ***don't*** add any conditionals on it, otherwise add a condition."

```
def self.by_make(make_name_str)
    if make_name_str == "all"
        where("cars.id > ?", 0)
    else
        make_id = Make.where(:name => make_name_str).first.id
        where(:make_id => make_id)
    end
end
```

Obviously the case where the string is "all" looks very hacked and is what my question is about.  How do I write it to return nothing - basically, don't add any scope in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your `Car` model:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  scope :by_make, lambda do |make|
    make == :all ? scoped : where(:make_id => Make.where(:name => make).first.id)
  end
end
```

**Note** If there's a default scope in the `Car` model you may want to consider using `unscoped` in the code above, depending on whether you want to include the default scope when selecting all cars.